# ionic image filters using camanJS too slow

Tags: angularjs, image, filter, camera, ionic-framework

now iam using ionic framework and making image based platform.

i find camanJS for image filters.

it's filter so varity and convenient.

and i used base64encoding not path.

```
Caman("/path/to/file.png", function () {
  this.brightness(5);
  this.render(function () {
    this.save("/path/to/output.png");
  });
});
```

but, changing image, for example none -> vintage style and others is so slow..

I am waiting for changing about 3 seconds..

how can i access this filters ?? any other libraries for image filter ??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?